# Cannnot move scenes in interface builder of XCode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

My problem is that I cannot move scenes after updating XCode to 6.1. They are quite distorted as u can see in a picture and I want to group them a bit. I know i can arrange them using source code of storyboard but may be there's simple way to allow just dragging them?

[image: It is 12.5% zoomed so every scene fits in]

Comment: I believe this is zoomed out to 12.5% and I also have faced this issue. Just try closing Xcode and opening it again. Then try to rearrange the scenes

Comment: I've tried it, I also created new project and it also has the similar problem .

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in your screenshot I think you just need to zoom in more, to be able to move them individually. I think its a little annoying.

Unless Its another issue, zoom in more you can do it by double clicking a few times

Comment: Zooming to 100% does not provide an ability to move scenes. I can neither move new added view controllers. They just stick in initial place after releasing.